# Painting in QGraphicsScene in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qpainter

I am trying to paint a line in a `QGraphicsScene`. I know how to add items in a scene but not how to add items in the scene that are drawn using painter. Below is the code I am trying to implement:

```
void MainWindow::drawLine(){
    painter->drawLine(100,10,200,20);
    item = ??
    scene->addItem(item);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    qDebug() << "Line Created";
}
```

As you may see, the item is not defined above. How to create an item for the same so that it is painted in the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inherit from `QGraphicsItem` and override the `paint` method. I found a nice tutorial regarding it: [tutorial.](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QGraphicsView_QGraphicsScene_QGraphicsItems.php)

Keep in mind that in your inherited item, you must implement at least the two pure virtual methods `paint` and `boundingRect`. You can see that these functions are pure virtual by looking in the documentation of `QGraphicsItem` : [QGraphicsItem.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html)

Comment: I am getting `error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'myitem'` on following the above tutorial. @kobigurk

Comment: @KamalpreetGrewal Maybe you haven't fully defined the inherited virtual function in the derived class.